# GLSL vertex shader not compiling

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL to try to make a 3D game, but I've run into an error I can't resolve on my own. Whenever I run the program, I get the error:

> java.lang.Exception: Error compiling shader code: 2

I set this error up myself to alert me if the shader failed to compile, which it seems to be doing every time, and I can't understand why.

```
public static String loadResource(String file) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
    String out = "";

    String s = reader.readLine();
    while (s != null){
        out += s + "\n";
        s = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
    return out;
}
```

That is the method I use to load the text of my shader code and place it into a string. I've asked it to print it out afterwards, and as far as i can tell there aren't any issues with it.

```
public void createVertexShader(String shaderCode) throws Exception{
    vertexShaderId = createShader(shaderCode, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
}

public void createFragmentShader(String shaderCode) throws Exception {
    vertexShaderId = createShader(shaderCode, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}
```

These two methods above use the following method to create the vertex and fragment shaders:

```
public int createShader(String shaderCode, int shaderType) throws Exception {
    int shaderId = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if(shaderId == 0){
        throw new Exception("Error creating shader code: " + shaderId);
    }

    glShaderSource(shaderId, shaderCode);
    glCompileShader(shaderId);

    if(glGetShaderi(shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0){
        throw new Exception("Error compiling shader code: " + shaderId);
    }

    glAttachShader(programId, shaderId);

    return shaderId;
}
```

The shader gets created with no errors, but when I check to see if it's been compiled properly, it throws the exception and stops my program. Here are my vertex and fragment shaders:

vertex.vs

```
#version 150

layout (location=0) in vec3 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);  
}
```

fragment.fs

```
#version 150

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

I have verified that I am using the correct GLSL version in my shaders, but I got the actual shader code from a tutorial, so I don't know if the syntax is strictly correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout (location=0) in vec3 pos;` this line will give you syntax error with #version 150 or below. Try #version 330 or higher in your vertex shader.

Also, in the vertex shader `pos` and `position` are different symbols and you've failed to provide a definition for `position`.